# Determine correct file type for Express.js server

Tags: windows, node.js, mime

I need to determine type of the file that I upload on Express.js server. There are ways by checking extension, or even checking something like this:

```
if(req.files.file.type !== "application/pdf") {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        return res.send({errormessage: "Only PDF accepted."});
    }
```

Problem here is that changing file extension on client side, will easily fool this check. I think that only check is to download the file on Express filesystem on do some kind of a check on it.
I have tried mime library for node.js, but it also depends on content-type, and thus is easily fooled as well.   I have seen another library:
    https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic

But it seems it is non Windows one. My server is Windows 2012 machine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

mmmagic should work on all platforms that node supports. If you are on Windows, you have to have the proper build environment though:

- Python 2.7.x
- Visual Studio/C++ 2010+ (If you use the Express edition, you will need to install the Windows SDK if you are compiling for 64-bit). If you use VS 2012+, make sure you download the "for Windows Desktop" version.